# bind -x leaves terminal in a state resembling ^V

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

I define a shell keybinding in my `~/.bashrc` like so:

```
bind -x '"\e\C-w":"/usr/bin/reset"'
```

This does make `Ctrl-Alt-w` launch the `reset` executable. However, it leaves the terminal in a state that resembles the one you get into by pressing `Ctrl-v`. So, for example, if immediately after resetting in this way I press `Ctrl-p`, instead of invoking the action of that shortcut (repeat previous command) I get `^P` printed.

Any idea what's causing this problem and how to fix it?

**EDIT**: I am attaching a Python program that reproduces the messed-up terminal state I am trying to fix with the `reset`. I encounter this condition very often while debugging multi-threaded applications:

```
import pdb, thread, time

def interrupt():
    time.sleep(2)
    pdb.set_trace()

thread.start_new_thread(interrupt, ())
raw_input('? ')
```

To reproduce the messed-up state, just run the code above, and press Enter when you see the debugger invoked (it will print a bunch of text, ending with `pdb.set_trace()`, about two seconds after you run the program and the initial prompt appears).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `reset` clears the terminal display and also resets all input settings to their default. In particular, it sets the input mode to [cooked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode), i.e. the terminal reads one line at a time before sending the whole line to the application (here, the application is bash). The terminal's line editor is an extremely primitive one that only understands backspace, nothing fancier. Bash provides a sophisticated line editor; it switches the terminal to raw mode, where each character is sent to the application as soon as it's typed.

If you find yourself with a messed up terminal (no line edition or no echo at the bash prompt), the easiest way to restore it is to run the command `reset` or `stty sane`. Usually you can type them blind and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. If that doesn't work (e.g. because the terminal is in cooked mode and the line submission character isn't the default one), you can run `reset 2>/dev/pts/42` (terminal reinitialization) or `stty sane </dev/pts/42` (input configuration reinitialization) (note the different redirections) where `/dev/pts/42` is the terminal that the shell is running in. Finding the terminal name if you can't run commands in it may take a bit of guessing. From within the terminal, the command `tty` would display it. If you can find the right bash process in the `ps` output, you want the `TTY` column, with `/dev` in front.

Running these commands by typing them at the bash prompt does the right thing, but running them as part of a readline macro not so much. Bash resets the terminal settings each time it prints a new prompt, so what you do during the edition of one line doesn't last until subsequent commands.

Furthermore, if you run `reset` during the edition of a line, this messes up the parameters that bash relies on: in particular, it sets the terminal mode to cooked, whereas bash line edition requires that the line editor receives the input character by character. Comparing the output of `stty` during a bash command line edition and while not at a bash prompt, I think these are the settings you need:

```
bind -x '"\e\C-w": "reset; stty -icrnl -icanon -echo </dev/tty"'
```

If you're calling `reset` only to clear the display, call `tput rs1 rs2 rs3 rf` instead of `reset`.

As I wrote above, the right way to reset the terminal settings is to run `reset` at the bash prompt. Running it as part of a key binding doesn't work because bash restores the settings left over by the last application (the one that left the terminal settings in a mess) when it displays the next prompt. I don't think bash has any built-in feature to instead reset terminal settings to a sane default, but you can do that with user configuration if you want, with the following line in your `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND
stty sane"
```

If you really want to have a key binding that resets the terminal settings during line edition, you need something more sophisticated. Cause bash to run the `reset` command at a prompt (as opposed to as part of an editing command) then resume the current edit. This isn't easy to do in bash because bindings can only be readline macros or bash functions but you can't mix the two. The following code binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to a readline macro that calls a bash function via a binding, then calls the `accept-line` readline function via its `\C-m` binding, and then calls another bash function via another binding. The [`bind -x` bindings can only be assigned to key sequences of length 1 or 2](http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/bash-execute-unix-command-cannot-find-keymap-for-command-td7531.html), so I use little-used `C-x LETTER` combinations for the helper macros.

```
run_command_during_line_edition () {
  saved_READLINE_LINE=$READLINE_LINE saved_READLINE_POINT=$READLINE_POINT
  READLINE_POINT=0 READLINE_LINE=" $1"
  unset run_command_first
}
restore_saved_command () {
  READLINE_LINE=$saved_READLINE_LINE READLINE_POINT=$saved_READLINE_POINT
  unset saved_READLINE_LINE saved_READLINE_POINT
}
bind -x '"\C-xZ": "restore_saved_command"'
bind -x '"\C-xR": "reset; stty sane -icrnl -icanon -echo; run_command_during_line_edition reset"'
bind '"\e\C-w": "\C-xR\r\C-xZ"'
```

Again, you probably don't need all that complication — blindly typing `reset` at the prompt, or including `stty sane` in your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, should solve your problem. Oh, or you could switch to zsh where all of this would be a breeze.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  How can I can `stty` and get its output "while not at the bash prompt?  P.S. I should clarify that running reset from the command line (instead of `bind -x`) leaves the terminal in good state. Moreover, your solution works when nothing is wrong in the terminal. But the reason I need this keyboard binding is to reset a messed up terminal (due to Python's pdb debugger being terminated by a separate thread) and your suggested binding now fails to fix that.

Comment: (Whereas the plain reset of before did fix it, but suffered from from the issue outlined above).

Comment: @DunPeal To see the terminal state while not at the bash prompt, simply run `stty` from the bash command line. To see the terminal state while at the bash prompt, run `tty` from the bash prompt, note the value (e.g. `/dev/pts/42`), and run `stty </dev/pts/42` from another terminal. The binding that I give does work when the terminal is messed up, it first calls `reset` which reaches a known state and then sets the options that bash needs. What went wrong for you?

Comment: I checked the difference between `stty` in and out of bash as you suggested, and it seems to be precisely the one you found - `-icrnl -icanon -echo` - so I defined the exact same binding you posted. Unfortunately, when I execute this shortcut at the messed-up state, it doesn't fix the two problems evident in that state: 1. Keyboard output is not echoed at the prompt, i.e. whatever I type doesn't appear on screen, 2. Pressing enter doesn't go to a new line, instead I get horizontal prompts: "$ $ $ $ ..."

Comment: Gilles, I edited my original question above to include a code sample that reproduces the "messed up" terminal state I am trying to fix with the reset. I'm not even entirely sure what the technical term for the problem is. I described it in my previous comment, and you can now reproduce it with that code.

Comment: @DunPeal Ok, I think I get it. The approach you've chosen is really hard — why don't you just type `reset` at the bash prompt? You can make an alias if that's too much typing. Doing it by typing a key is hard, and won't even work if the terminal is in raw mode (you'll have to press Return for bash to see the input).

Comment: Gilles, thanks!  The reason I wanted shortcut for it is that I am debugging a lot of threaded applications for my current project, and so I end up in this messed up mode as often as 2-3 times per minute. It seemed like a bind should work. Anyway, I can actually do it by `bind '"\e\C-w":"reset\n"'`. The downside is that I get the `reset` command in my history, so for example if I press Ctrl-p to bring back the last command before the reset (which I also do **a lot**) then I get the useless reset instead of the actual last command. Not a huge deal, though it would have been nice if it worked.

Comment: @DunPeal Adding `stty sane` to `PROMPT_COMMAND` sounds like the right solution for you. If you want to keep some commands out of your history, you can set `HISTCONTROL='ignorespace'` and type a space before the command.

Comment: Gilles, thanks so much!  `stty sane` appears to be **exactly** the action to fix the messed-up state. As a boon, it's much faster than a full `reset`!  And your advice about `HISTCONTROL` is gold too. I just added a shortcut to run `stty sane` and set `HISTCONTROL` to ignore it.